# How to update row of dataTable celleditor

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to implement a primefaces data table with cell editing.

```
  <p:dataTable id="table" var="data" value="#{bean.liste}"
                     editable="true" 
                     editMode="cell" 
                     widgetVar="cellInter"
                     styleClass="hovered striped table tblDataTable" >          
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}"   />            
             <p:column  sortBy="#{data.type}" filterBy="#{data.type}"    filterMatchMode="contains"  >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <span class="nomColonneTab"  >Type  </span>
                </f:facet>
                <p:cellEditor>                
                    <f:facet name="output">               
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{data.type}"/> 
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:inputText value="#{data.type}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor> 
            </p:column>
```

but when I click on the datatable to change the value of type it doesnt change

here is my function :

```
  public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

        if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);


        }               
    }
```

Comment: In your question it isn't entirely clear what you are wanting to update, but whatever it is, you need to specify that item's id in the `update` attribute of your `<p:ajax>` tag.  Right now, you have nothing.

Comment: The question is implying that `newValue` didn't contain the submitted value, but the old value. On the other hand, it could also be as good possible that OP is focusing way too much on whether the added faces message would show up instead of on whether the method is actually called and the `newValue` variable actually contains the submitted value (e.g. by checking in the debugger). His code indeed doesn't show anywhere if and how he's displaying those messages.

Comment: newValue does not contain the submitted value. I always get the old value!